# Failed to complete Gradle execution when i use "compile project"

Tags: android

This is my first gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.hairlookapp.hairlook"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    apt 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare-compiler:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile project(':AndTinder')
}
```

and this is the second gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.4'
}
```

When i compile, Android Studio say "Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: ".

If i remove `compile project(':AndTinder')` it works, but i cannot use that project.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Can I assume that the second gradle file is from the AndTinder library project?

Comment: Could you provide your settings.gradle?

Comment: Extractly, the second gradle is from the library. This is the settings.gradle: include ':app', ':AndTinder'